# Yarn container cleanup

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I have a Yarn container which needs to mount something to the local filesystem when it runs. Is there a way to clean this up (do the unmount operation) when the container is cleaned up by Yarn?

Comment: Do you mean application manager?

Comment: My application manager requests and launches containers for my application, and each launched container needs to do a mount. I'd like to register the unmount cleanup task with Yarn so that cleanup will occur even if my container processes (including the application manager) are force-killed.

Comment: You are saying each container does a mount. Is this happening in a mapper task (assuming it is a mapreduce job)?

Comment: I'm not doing anything related to MapReduce, I just want to use Yarn for resource sharing/negotiation, similar to Mesos.

Comment: @AAudibert From the Hadoop code, I could not find any clue to achieve this. If it was a MapReduce job, then during the cleanup phase of a mapper or a reducer, you could have achieved this. But, this is a good question (+1 for asking this) and I would love to get an answer for this.